# Python3.8.3: Conversion of input string to integer results to ValueError

Tags: python-3.x

Code:

```
age = int(input('How old are you? '))
```

Error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

I just implement what the code state in ATBS book. What did I do wrong? Thoughts and help will be much appreciated

Comment: It looks like you pressed enter instead of replying a number, so `int(input())` failed because `input()` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is correct. It works for me. You can check it here: [Online check](https://repl.it/repls/AppropriateInfiniteBases)

```
age = int(input('How old are you? '))
print(type(age))

# output

How old are you? 20
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, AREPL(a real time error detection) did show the error, I didn't actually run it. Yes it runs correctly on terminal. Im sorry, i am new to this. Thank you!!